# LINQ expression to compare nested arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, ienumerable

I have a list of lines, a line consists of an array of LatLngs (latitude/longitudes), therefore, this is how the list is represented.

```
IEnumerable<LatLng[]> lineNetwork;
```

I'm trying to work out the LINQ expression needed to return all the lines in `lineNetwork` that are connected to a `givenLine`. To be connected they must have a Latitude and Longitude equal to a Latitude and Longitude in the `givenLine`.

```
LatLng[] givenLine = 
{ 
    new LatLng(Latitude: 0.1, Longitude: 0.1),
    new LatLng(Latitude: 0.2, Longitude: 0.2),
    new LatLng(Latitude: 0.3, Longitude: 0.3)
}

IEnumerable<LatLng[]> connectedLines = lineNetwork.LINQEXPRESSIONRETURNSCONNECTEDLINES(givenLine);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `LatLng` is equatable you can use `Intersect`

```
var result = lineNetwork.Where (n => n.Intersect(givenLine).Any())
```

Since `Intersect` use a hashtable for lookup internally it will yield very good performance.

Comment: In addition to the answer, could anyone tell me how it would be changed in the circumstance that 'givenLine' is actually a list of givenLines, i.e. IEnumerable<LatLng[]> givenLines? Or should I start a new thread for that?

Comment: change givenLine in expression to `givenLines.SelectMany(x => x)`

Comment: `Since Intersect use a hashtable for lookup internally it will yield very good performance.` Unfortunately, the cost of doing that is creating `M` hashtables - where `M` is `lineNetwork.Count()`. As such, a _likely_ better performing solution (but it depends on the size of `lineNetwork` and the size of `givenLine`) is to do it the other way around. Generate a `bob` `HashSet` from `givenLine` (once) and then use `lineNetwork.Where (n => n.Any(z => bob.Contains(z)))`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably should define equality for LatLng type, which I assume is a struct.

Your query would go something like

```
var connectedLines = lineNetwork.Where( line => line.Any( coord => givenLine.Contains( coord ) ) );
```

Here, I am assuming given correct equality implementation `Contains()` will return true.

Comment: This if `LatLng` overloads the `Equals`... Otherwise instead of the `Contains` you'll have to use a second `.Any()`

Comment: Can be simplified to `line.Any(givenLine.Contains)`.

Comment: @xanatos Agreed.

Comment: In addition to the answer, could anyone tell me how it would be changed in the circumstance that 'givenLine' is actually a list of givenLines, i.e. IEnumerable<LatLng[]> givenLines? Or should I start a new thread for that?